# Получаю ошибку Not Found при клике увеличения изображения

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, bxslider

Есть [сайт со слайдером проектов с зумированием изображений](http://www.alibanisadr.com/paintings/age)
Хочу себе сделать такого же плана с сохранением стилей. 
Сам слайдер проектов перенес, все ок, но есть проблема с просмотром картинок в увеличенном виде - выскакивает в консоли ошибка `jquery`

> GET
>   http://site.ru/category/painting/age/featured-works?view=enlarge&go-away-chrome=1
>   404 (Not Found)

Насколько я понимаю это связано с тем, что у меня путь к странице несколько другой `/paint/age/featured-works?view=enlarge`

```
<img class='enlarge zoom-image high-quality bx-image'
data-href="/painting/age/featured-works?view=enlarge" data-slide='1'
data-src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/2020x1160_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/c1d1f86223877c96957cf5718d6faf36.jpeg' data-srcset="https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/1010x580_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/c1d1f86223877c96957cf5718d6faf36.jpeg 1x, [url]https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/2020x1160_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/c1d1f86223877c96957cf5718d6faf36.jpeg[/url] 2x" data-enlarge='https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/enlarge/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/c1d1f86223877c96957cf5718d6faf36.jpeg'  data-zoom="true" data-zoom-src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/zoom/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/c1d1f86223877c96957cf5718d6faf36.jpeg" alt=''>
```

Пытался разные пути прописывать, но все тщетно. Набросал [код с используемым функционалом](http://jsfiddle.net/t9rnz01L/)

```js
var langInUrl = false;
var closeText = "Close";
var zoomText = "Zoom";
var screens = {};
var frontendParams = {
  currentScreen: null,
};
$("body").on("click", ".zoom-click", function(h) {
  h.preventDefault();
  var d = getOrCreateOverlay();
  d.find(".enlarge-wrapper").hide();
  $('<div id="zoomImage" oncontextmenu="/*return false;*/">                    <div id="zoomHeaderWrapper"><div id="zoomHeader">                            <div id="zoomHeaderClose">' + closeText + '</div>                            <div id="zoomHeaderText"></div></div></div><div id="zoomWrap">             <div id="pan"><img id="panImage" src="" srcset="" />                        </div></div><div id="zoomFooterWrapper"><div id="zoomFooter">                  <div class="content-conveyor ui-helper-clearfix">                              <div class = "zoomFooterControl" id="zoomFooterZoomOut"></div>                <div id="jQslider"></div><div class="zoomFooterControl"  id="zoomFooterZoomIn"></div></div></div></div>              </div>').show().appendTo(d);
  $("#zoomImage").css("background-color", $("#overlay").css("background-color"));
  var g = function() {
    var l = 3.5;
    var e = {
      minScale: 1,
      maxScale: l,
      contain: "invert"
    };
    if ($(window).width() > 767) {
      var k = $("#jQslider").slider({
        animate: true,
        range: "min",
        value: 1,
        min: 1,
        max: l,
        step: 0.05,
        slide: function(m, n) {
          $panzoom.panzoom("zoom", n.value)
        }
      });
      $.extend(e, {
        "$zoomIn": $("#zoomFooterZoomIn"),
        "$zoomOut": $("#zoomFooterZoomOut"),
        onZoom: function(o, n, p, m) {
          k.slider("value", p)
        }
      })
    }
    $panzoom = $("#pan").panzoom(e);
    $panzoom.parent().on("mousewheel.focal", function(n) {
      n.preventDefault();
      var o = n.delta || n.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
      var m = o ? o < 0 : n.originalEvent.deltaY > 0;
      $panzoom.panzoom("zoom", m, {
        increment: 0.1,
        animate: false,
        focal: n
      })
    });
    var j = new Hammer.Manager(document.getElementById("panImage"));
    j.add(new Hammer.Tap({
      event: "doubletap",
      taps: 2,
      interval: 500,
      threshold: 10,
      posThreshold: 100
    }));
    j.add(new Hammer.Tap({
      event: "singletap",
      interval: 500,
      threshold: 10,
      posThreshold: 100
    }));
    j.get("doubletap").recognizeWith("singletap");
    j.get("singletap").requireFailure("doubletap");
    j.on("doubletap", function(m) {
      if ($panzoom.panzoom("getMatrix")[0] == 1) {
        var o = (m.center.x - ($("#pan").width() / 2)) * 2.5;
        var n = (m.center.y - ($("#pan").height() / 2)) * 2.5;
        $panzoom.panzoom("zoom", 2.5);
        $panzoom.panzoom("pan", -o, -n)
      } else {
        $panzoom.panzoom("zoom", 1)
      }
    })
  };
  var f;
  if ($(h.target).is("img")) {
    f = $(h.target);
    $("#zoomHeaderClose").click(function() {
      $("#overlay").remove();
      $("body").removeAttr("style")
    })
  } else {
    f = $("#overlay .fader-items .slide:eq(" + sliderHandler.getCurrentSlide() + ") img");
    $("#zoomHeaderClose").click(function() {
      d.find(".enlarge-wrapper").show();
      $("#zoomImage").remove()
    })
  }
  collageDispatcher.trigger("panzoom.beforeImageLoad", f);
  $("#panImage").load(g).attr("src", f.data("zoom-src") ? f.data("zoom-src") : f.data("enlarge")).attr("srcset", f.data("zoom-srcset") ? f.data("zoom-srcset") : f.data("enlarge-srcset"));
  if (f.hasClass("high-quality")) {
    $("#panImage").addClass("high-quality")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contentWrapper">
  <section id='featured-works'>
    <div id="multiple-slider-container">
      <div id="screen-featured-works">
        <div id="featured-works">
          <div id='slider-container'>
            <div id='screen-featured-works'>
              <div class='container
                          '>
                <div id='featured-works-container'>
                  <div class='
                              slider                                 full-slider
                              '>
                    <div data-screen="featured-works" class='fader-items
                                bx-preload
                                '>
                      <div class='slide'>
                        <figure class="">
                          <img class='
                                      enlarge            zoom-image            high-quality            bx-image        ' data-href="/paint/age/featured-works?view=enlarge" data-slide='1' data-src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/2020x1160_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/c1d1f86223877c96957cf5718d6faf36.jpeg'
                            data-srcset="https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/1010x580_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/c1d1f86223877c96957cf5718d6faf36.jpeg 1x, https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/2020x1160_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/c1d1f86223877c96957cf5718d6faf36.jpeg 2x"
                            data-enlarge='https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/enlarge/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/c1d1f86223877c96957cf5718d6faf36.jpeg' data-zoom="true" data-zoom-src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/zoom/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/c1d1f86223877c96957cf5718d6faf36.jpeg"
                            alt=''>
                        </figure>
                        <figcaption>
                          <p>&quot;Age&quot;, 2015, Oil on Linen, 66x88 inches&nbsp;
                          </p>
                        </figcaption>
                      </div>
                      <div class='slide'>
                        <figure class="">
                          <img class='
                                      enlarge                        high-quality            bx-image        ' data-href="/paint/age/featured-works?view=enlarge" data-slide='2' data-src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/2020x1160_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/d1f83aa674c4f2d7016c4ef5db3acf82.jpeg'
                            data-srcset="https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/1010x580_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/d1f83aa674c4f2d7016c4ef5db3acf82.jpeg 1x, https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/2020x1160_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/d1f83aa674c4f2d7016c4ef5db3acf82.jpeg 2x"
                            data-enlarge='https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/enlarge/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/d1f83aa674c4f2d7016c4ef5db3acf82.jpeg' alt=''>
                        </figure>
                        <figcaption>
                          <p>&quot;Age&quot;, Detail
                          </p>
                        </figcaption>
                      </div>
                      <div class='slide'>
                        <figure class="">
                          <img class='
                                      enlarge                        high-quality            bx-image        ' data-href="/paint/age/featured-works?view=enlarge" data-slide='3' data-src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/2020x1160_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/acc52a4c88337bd1187f921c5339aab8.jpeg'
                            data-srcset="https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/1010x580_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/acc52a4c88337bd1187f921c5339aab8.jpeg 1x, https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/2020x1160_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/acc52a4c88337bd1187f921c5339aab8.jpeg 2x"
                            data-enlarge='https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/enlarge/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/acc52a4c88337bd1187f921c5339aab8.jpeg' alt=''>
                        </figure>
                        <figcaption>
                          <p>&quot;Age&quot;, Detail
                          </p>
                        </figcaption>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bx-thumbs">
                      <a href="" data-slide-index="0">
                        <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/260x180_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/c1d1f86223877c96957cf5718d6faf36.jpeg" srcset="https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/130x90_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/c1d1f86223877c96957cf5718d6faf36.jpeg 1x, https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/260x180_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/c1d1f86223877c96957cf5718d6faf36.jpeg 2x"
                          alt="" />
                      </a>
                      <a href="" data-slide-index="1">
                        <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/260x180_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/d1f83aa674c4f2d7016c4ef5db3acf82.jpeg" srcset="https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/130x90_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/d1f83aa674c4f2d7016c4ef5db3acf82.jpeg 1x, https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/260x180_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/d1f83aa674c4f2d7016c4ef5db3acf82.jpeg 2x"
                          alt="" />
                      </a>
                      <a href="" data-slide-index="2">
                        <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/260x180_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/acc52a4c88337bd1187f921c5339aab8.jpeg" srcset="https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/130x90_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/acc52a4c88337bd1187f921c5339aab8.jpeg 1x, https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/260x180_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/acc52a4c88337bd1187f921c5339aab8.jpeg 2x"
                          alt="" />
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Может быть подскажете, что мне нужно поправить?

Comment: У вас нерабочая ссылка на код, поправьте пожалуйста, а лучше воспользуйтесь местным сниппетом.

Comment: @Anton Mironov спасибо, поправил. Правда в таком виде он не особо рабочий, но сам смысл передает. Не думаю, что `js` проблема, т.к. на сайте он отрабатывает, а вот в путях или неправильном подулючении возможно.. Причем, саму область с кнопками загружает, а вот картинку - нет..

Comment: @Anton Mironov если я ссылку на тестовый сайт предоставлю - вы сможете помочь разобраться?

Comment: Сделайте воспроизводимой ошибку на jsfiddle или добавьте ссылку на тестовый сайт, это поможет быстрее разобраться в вашей проблеме.

Comment: @SergeyN ссылка на тестовый сайт http://a-lot-of-money.ru/dwp/paint/age/

Comment: @Вася код на указанном сайта минифицированный и тяжело поддается отладке.

Comment: @SergeyN да, я в курсе, сам вторую неделю мучаюсь, пытаюсь решить проблему, что только уже не пробовал. Вот задал вопрос, установил за него конкурс - может быть найдется эксперт, который подскажет в чем причина

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Первое, что бросается в глаза - обработчик события для тега $("body") повешен вне области $(document).ready(). Страница еще не загрузилась полностью, когда выполнился данный скрипт. И скрипт, соответственно, просто не увидел нужных ему объектов, т.к. тег загрузился ПОСЛЕ выполнения скрипта.
2. Указывайте версию библиотек, которые используете, т.к. вашу ошибку воспроизвести не удалось. Консоль - пуста (с версией jQuery 3.2.1). Разобравшись со временем с исходным кодом с галереи стало понятно, что используется библиотека jQuery версии 1.11.2.
3. Так же вы абсолютно ничего не сказано, КАКИЕ именно дополнительные библиотеки подключили, чем ввели остальных пользователей сайта, желающих вам помочь в заблуждение. В будущем указывайте эту информацию, чтобы было легче разобраться и помочь.
4. Отсутствуют подключенные CSS-стили.
5. По синтаксису получаемой ошибки. Скрипт осуществляет попытку открыть файл вне браузера, что запрещено политикой безопасности Chrome. Иначе бы можно было получать доступ к файлам пользователя на жестком диске. Ошибка, генерируемая в конечном счете: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
6. Если откроете сайт с плагином и посмотрите вкладку "Network", то увидите запрос http://www.alibanisadr.com/paintings/age/featured-works?view=enlarge&go-away-chrome=1 который возвращает HTML-код. Все, что вам нужно для решения вашей задачи - это создать подобную страницу у себя, которая возвращала бы вам нужные данные.

Здесь не могу прикрепить архив. Структура каталога с проектом в моем случае:

```
+ /js/script.js - JS-скрипт, приведенный в примере
|
+ index.html - главная страница с галереей
|
+ enlarge.html - генерируемый HTML-код запроса
```

Код index.html и script.js:

```js
var langInUrl = false;
var closeText = "Close";
var zoomText = "Zoom";
var screens = {};
var frontendParams = {
    currentScreen: null
};

$( document).ready(function(){

    $(".zoom-click").on("click", function(h) {
        h.preventDefault();

        var d = getOrCreateOverlay();
        d.find(".enlarge-wrapper").hide();
        $('<div id="zoomImage" oncontextmenu="/*return false;*/">                    <div id="zoomHeaderWrapper"><div id="zoomHeader">                            <div id="zoomHeaderClose">' + closeText + '</div>                            <div id="zoomHeaderText"></div></div></div><div id="zoomWrap">             <div id="pan"><img id="panImage" src="" srcset="" />                        </div></div><div id="zoomFooterWrapper"><div id="zoomFooter">                  <div class="content-conveyor ui-helper-clearfix">                              <div class = "zoomFooterControl" id="zoomFooterZoomOut"></div>                <div id="jQslider"></div><div class="zoomFooterControl"  id="zoomFooterZoomIn"></div></div></div></div>              </div>').show().appendTo(d);
        $("#zoomImage").css("background-color", $("#overlay").css("background-color"));
        var g = function() {
            var l = 3.5;
            var e = {
                minScale: 1,
                maxScale: l,
                contain: "invert"
            };
            if ( $(window).width() > 767) {
                var k = $("#jQslider").slider({
                    animate: true,
                    range: "min",
                    value: 1,
                    min: 1,
                    max: l,
                    step: 0.05,
                    slide: function(m, n) {
                        $panzoom.panzoom("zoom", n.value)
                    }
                });
                $.extend(e, {
                    "$zoomIn": $("#zoomFooterZoomIn"),
                    "$zoomOut": $("#zoomFooterZoomOut"),
                    onZoom: function(o, n, p, m) {
                        k.slider("value", p)
                    }
                })
            }
            $panzoom = $("#pan").panzoom(e);
            $panzoom.parent().on("mousewheel.focal", function(n) {
                n.preventDefault();
                var o = n.delta || n.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
                var m = o ? o < 0 : n.originalEvent.deltaY > 0;
                $panzoom.panzoom("zoom", m, {
                    increment: 0.1,
                    animate: false,
                    focal: n
                })
            });
            var j = new Hammer.Manager(document.getElementById("panImage"));
            j.add(new Hammer.Tap({
                event: "doubletap",
                taps: 2,
                interval: 500,
                threshold: 10,
                posThreshold: 100
            }));
            j.add(new Hammer.Tap({
                event: "singletap",
                interval: 500,
                threshold: 10,
                posThreshold: 100
            }));
            j.get("doubletap").recognizeWith("singletap");
            j.get("singletap").requireFailure("doubletap");
            j.on("doubletap", function(m) {
                if ($panzoom.panzoom("getMatrix")[0] == 1) {
                    var o = (m.center.x - ($("#pan").width() / 2)) * 2.5;
                    var n = (m.center.y - ($("#pan").height() / 2)) * 2.5;
                    $panzoom.panzoom("zoom", 2.5);
                    $panzoom.panzoom("pan", -o, -n)
                } else {
                    $panzoom.panzoom("zoom", 1)
                }
            })
        };
        var f;
        if ( $(h.target).is("img") ) {
            f = $(h.target);
            $("#zoomHeaderClose").click(function() {
                $("#overlay").remove();
                $("body").removeAttr("style")
            })
        } else {
            f = $("#overlay .fader-items .slide:eq(" + sliderHandler.getCurrentSlide() + ") img");
            $("#zoomHeaderClose").click(function() {
                d.find(".enlarge-wrapper").show();
                $("#zoomImage").remove()
            })
        }
        collageDispatcher.trigger("panzoom.beforeImageLoad", f);
        $("#panImage").load(g).
            attr("src", f.data("zoom-src") ? f.data("zoom-src") : f.data("enlarge")).
            attr("srcset", f.data("zoom-srcset") ? f.data("zoom-srcset") : f.data("enlarge-srcset"));
        if (f.hasClass("high-quality")) {
            $("#panImage").addClass("high-quality")
        }

    });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.alibanisadr.com/css/9ddf051.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fast.fonts.net/cssapi/f9c0ea93-78e6-466d-b5e6-bbbaae95f824.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.alibanisadr.com/style.cfdcfd09d41c637e5c0f2c3fb06f5633.css" />
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.alibanisadr.com/js/888b56b.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.alibanisadr.com/js/87f086e.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.alibanisadr.com/js/7240d26.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.alibanisadr.com/scripts.7256e61d4c89a09ebe1c0664d69a0eeb.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body data-email-protected="" data-section-key="paintings" data-section-id="55f9e06a6aa72c5b39b1c098" class="s-paintings detail-page">
<div class="contentWrapper">
    <section id='featured-works'>
        <div id="multiple-slider-container">
            <div id="screen-featured-works">
                <div id="featured-works">
                    <div id='slider-container'>
                        <div id='screen-featured-works'>
                            <div class='container'>
                                <div id='featured-works-container'>
                                    <div class='slider full-slider'>
                                        <div data-screen="featured-works" class='fader-items bx-preload'>
                                            <div class='slide'>
                                                <figure class="">
                                                    <img class='enlarge zoom-image high-quality bx-image'
                                                            data-href="enlarge.html?view=enlarge"
                                                            data-slide='1'
                                                            data-src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/2020x1160_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/c1d1f86223877c96957cf5718d6faf36.jpeg'
                                                            data-srcset="https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/1010x580_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/c1d1f86223877c96957cf5718d6faf36.jpeg 1x, https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/2020x1160_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/c1d1f86223877c96957cf5718d6faf36.jpeg 2x"
                                                            data-enlarge='https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/enlarge/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/c1d1f86223877c96957cf5718d6faf36.jpeg'
                                                            data-zoom="true"
                                                            data-zoom-src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/zoom/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/c1d1f86223877c96957cf5718d6faf36.jpeg"
                                                            alt=''
                                                            >
                                                </figure>
                                                <figcaption>
                                                    <p>&quot;Age&quot;, 2015, Oil on Linen, 66x88 inches&nbsp;
                                                    </p>
                                                </figcaption>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class='slide'>
                                                <figure class="">
                                                    <img class='enlarge high-quality bx-image'
                                                            data-href="enlarge.html?view=enlarge"
                                                            data-slide='2'
                                                            data-src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/2020x1160_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/d1f83aa674c4f2d7016c4ef5db3acf82.jpeg'
                                                            data-srcset="https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/1010x580_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/d1f83aa674c4f2d7016c4ef5db3acf82.jpeg 1x, https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/2020x1160_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/d1f83aa674c4f2d7016c4ef5db3acf82.jpeg 2x"
                                                            data-enlarge='https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/enlarge/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/d1f83aa674c4f2d7016c4ef5db3acf82.jpeg'
                                                            alt=''
                                                            >
                                                </figure>
                                                <figcaption>
                                                    <p>&quot;Age&quot;, Detail
                                                    </p>
                                                </figcaption>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class='slide'>
                                                <figure class="">
                                                    <img class='enlarge high-quality bx-image'
                                                            data-href="enlarge.html?view=enlarge"
                                                            data-slide='3'
                                                            data-src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/2020x1160_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/acc52a4c88337bd1187f921c5339aab8.jpeg'
                                                            data-srcset="https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/1010x580_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/acc52a4c88337bd1187f921c5339aab8.jpeg 1x, https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/2020x1160_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/acc52a4c88337bd1187f921c5339aab8.jpeg 2x"
                                                            data-enlarge='https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/enlarge/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/acc52a4c88337bd1187f921c5339aab8.jpeg'
                                                            alt=''
                                                            >
                                                </figure>
                                                <figcaption>
                                                    <p>&quot;Age&quot;, Detail
                                                    </p>
                                                </figcaption>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="bx-thumbs">
                                            <a href="" data-slide-index="0">
                                                <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/260x180_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/c1d1f86223877c96957cf5718d6faf36.jpeg"
                                                     srcset="https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/130x90_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/c1d1f86223877c96957cf5718d6faf36.jpeg 1x, https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/260x180_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/c1d1f86223877c96957cf5718d6faf36.jpeg 2x"
                                                     alt=""/>
                                            </a>
                                            <a href="" data-slide-index="1">
                                                <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/260x180_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/d1f83aa674c4f2d7016c4ef5db3acf82.jpeg"
                                                     srcset="https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/130x90_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/d1f83aa674c4f2d7016c4ef5db3acf82.jpeg 1x, https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/260x180_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/d1f83aa674c4f2d7016c4ef5db3acf82.jpeg 2x"
                                                     alt=""/>
                                            </a>
                                            <a href="" data-slide-index="2">
                                                <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/260x180_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/acc52a4c88337bd1187f921c5339aab8.jpeg"
                                                     srcset="https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/130x90_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/acc52a4c88337bd1187f921c5339aab8.jpeg 1x, https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/260x180_fit/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/acc52a4c88337bd1187f921c5339aab8.jpeg 2x"
                                                     alt=""/>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Код страницы enlarge.html

```html
<div id='screen-featured-works' >
    <div>
        <div id='featured-works-container'>
            <div class='full-slider'>
                <div data-screen="featured-works" class='fader-items bx-preload'>
                    <div class='slide'>
                        <figure class="">
                            <img class='zoom-image high-quality bx-image'
                                 data-slide='1'
                                 data-src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/enlarge/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/c1d1f86223877c96957cf5718d6faf36.jpeg'        data-enlarge='https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/enlarge/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/c1d1f86223877c96957cf5718d6faf36.jpeg'                    data-zoom="true"
                                 data-zoom-src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/zoom/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/c1d1f86223877c96957cf5718d6faf36.jpeg"                alt=''
                                 src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/enlarge/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/c1d1f86223877c96957cf5718d6faf36.jpeg' >
                        </figure>
                        <figcaption>
                            <p>&quot;Age&quot;, 2015, Oil on Linen, 66x88 inches&nbsp;</p>
                        </figcaption>
                    </div>
                    <div class='slide'>
                        <figure class="">
                            <img class='high-quality bx-image'
                                 data-slide='2'
                                 data-src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/enlarge/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/d1f83aa674c4f2d7016c4ef5db3acf82.jpeg'        data-enlarge='https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/enlarge/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/d1f83aa674c4f2d7016c4ef5db3acf82.jpeg'                alt=''
                                 src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/enlarge/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/d1f83aa674c4f2d7016c4ef5db3acf82.jpeg' >
                        </figure>

                        <figcaption>
                            <p>&quot;Age&quot;, Detail</p>
                        </figcaption>
                    </div>
                    <div class='slide'>
                        <figure class="">
                            <img class='high-quality bx-image'
                                 data-slide='3'
                                 data-src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/enlarge/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/acc52a4c88337bd1187f921c5339aab8.jpeg'        data-enlarge='https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/enlarge/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/acc52a4c88337bd1187f921c5339aab8.jpeg'                alt=''
                                 src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.collageplatform.com.prod/image_cache/enlarge/55f9dfbb6aa72c7039b1c099/acc52a4c88337bd1187f921c5339aab8.jpeg' >
                        </figure>

                        <figcaption>
                            <p>&quot;Age&quot;, Detail</p>
                        </figcaption>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за интересные мысли. Я давно сбрасывал ссылку на тестовый сайт, правда другому пользователю в комментариях, возможно вы не видели  - вот
http://a-lot-of-money.ru/dwp/paint/age/
`Все, что вам нужно для решения вашей задачи - это создать подобную страницу у себя, которая возвращала бы вам нужные данные.` Поверьте, 2 недели бьюсь над решением задачи и какие только ссылки не указывал.. не понимаю в чем дело и почему код не отдает 200

Comment: @Вася, вполне возможно, что страница действительно не найдена. Попробуйте, как в примере выше заменить код в теге img на data-href="enlarge.html?view=enlarge" data-slide='1' и положить в корень файл с именем enlarge.html (код файла привел выше) и посмотреть результат.

Comment: такс, ну вот, сделал как вы сказали. Ошибки сейчас не показывает, но вместо этого белую увеличенную область экрана со слайдером

Comment: @Вася, попробуйте так же создать файл index.html с кодом, который привел выше. Изначально, попробуйте где-то у себя локально создать папку с содержимым ./index.html, ./enlarge.html и /js/script.js без всего лишнего. Просто скопировать текст выше и вставить. И посмотреть, заработает ли.

Comment: да, заработал! Вы умница! Только бы осталось перенести на итог, почему html вдруг работает..
http://a-lot-of-money.ru/dwp/wp-content/themes/dubach/main.html

Comment: @Вася, спасибо :) Как итог, почему работает, постарался описать выше: не было нужных классов в тегах img, не были полностью подключены все js-библиотеки, уходил запрос на несуществующую страницу. Исправив это, галерея заработала :)

Comment: но, как я понимаю, только первый слайдер отрабатывает? или у меня одного только так?

Comment: @Вася, посмотрел - да. Завтра посмотрю, в чем дело.

Comment: окей, буду ждать. +50 баллов за вопрос уйдут вам

Comment: @Вася, давайте сначала попробую разобраться.

Comment: не получилось пока разобраться?

Comment: @Вася, вчера, к сожалению не успел посмотреть. Постараюсь посмотреть сегодня.
Основная причина, на мой взгляд, это то, что на 1м слайдере идет запрос в корень, где эмулируемый ответ в виде файла enlarge.html удается найти, а на 2м и последующих слайдах идет запрос на НЕсуществующие URI: index.html/overlay?view=slider#3
Т.к. указанного адреса не существует, то и возникает ошибка. Это в теории, надо еще проверить.

Comment: окей, буду ждать рещультатов. Удасться это решить - можно будет инспектировать ошибку изначальную

Comment: пока никаких результатов?

Comment: @Вася, долго не мог ответить, не успевал. Обновил файл index.html. Удалил из тега a, что идет перед изображением класс class="zoom-click" и заработало. Простите, что вначале ввел в заблуждение. Масштабировать изображение можно только 1-е. Посмотрел на сайт, откуда брался скрипт, там точно так же можно увеличить только первое, два последние не увеличиваются с дополнительной увеличительной линейкой.

Comment: @Вася, перевел файлы на сервер и попробовал запустить их как htt://mysite.ru/, дублируется / в пути. На работу галереи это не влияет, только откуда там берется дополнительный / так и не понял. Чтобы разобраться, нужно будет скачивать скрипты и деобфусцировать их, затем дебажить и разбрираться, что почем. Сразу говорю - это может быть долгий нудный процесс. По самой работе - вроде все ок.

Comment: понял, спасибо за ответ. Вот такого рода таски помогают нам осваивать работу скриптов и библиотек гораздо глубже

Answer (score 2):

Отрываем сайт-донор, открываем отладчик (сеть, xhr), жмём на картинку и видим запрос `paintings/age/featured-works?view=enlarge&go-away-chrome=1`, смотрим что он возвращает (в отладчике). А возвращает он ответ с кодом 200 и кусок html'я с картинками (который вероятно используется js'ом). У вас такой же запрос возвращает код 404. Соответственно проблема вероятнее всего не на стороне клиента, а на стороне сервера. Верните код 200 и html с картинками как на сайте-доноре.

Comment: спасибо за подсказку, я воспроизвел ошибку на тестовом сайте, здесь тоже отдает 404.
a-lot-of-money.ru/dwp/paint/age 
2 недели мучаюсь, экспериментирую с ссылками и не только, не могу понять причину почему так..

Comment: @Вася вам удалось решить проблему? Дело в том, что у вас нет нужного обработчика на стороне сервера. Вы используете какую-то cms?

Comment: пока нет, не удалось, в процессе. Да, использую wordpress